# A movie where two teenagers save humanity from harvesting by aliens

Tags: story-identification, movie, space, alien-invasion

A B-movie from early 2000s, probably. It might have been based on a comic.

A teenage boy (young adult, maybe) somehow discovers an alien ship that belonged to some kind of space rangers. On the ship, the guy learns that humanity was seeded to Earth by some carnivore arachnids millions of years ago, only to be harvested for food.
Then, with a girl, who becomes the second pilot, they save humanity.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you see this?  I assume it was live-action?  What language was it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is *[Laserhawk](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0127640/?ref_=tt_urv)* (1997).

> Teenagers in a mid-west town discover that they are destined to fight off an alien invasion as the crew of a spacecraft of unknown origin. They are aided by a mysterious patient in a psychiatric hospital and a frenetic comic book artist.

The film opens with the following voiceover (and the caption, "250 million years ago..."), which matches the basic premise that you described. And the climax of the film does involve a young man and woman piloting a spacecraft of some sort.

> An alien lifeform known as Arachtoids has germinated Earth to serve as a future resource for food. Opposed to such harvesting practices, a benevolent lifeform has vowed to protect Earth and other planets from these creatures. Travelling in a ship called Laserhawk, these peacekeepers travel through time to the year 1984, where they inhabit the bodies of three humans who will one day save our planet from their return, and the human species from certain destruction.

Comment: @user143007 - If anyone correctly identifies the movie you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Thanks.